# Is it possible purge specific jms message from queue spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-jms

The use case is that, if I have a payment request message to activemq queue, how can I purge the specific message if it not consumed (in case payment is reversed)?

Answer (score 0):

Only the way I’m aware of is the `filter` during queue consuming:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#filter